# MySQL database - error when backup database

Tags: mysql, linux, cakephp

When i try do database backup in Linux i got this error,

"Got error: 1296: Got error 157 'Unknown error code' from NDBCLUSTER when using LOCK TABLE"

can someone please guide me what i have to do to solve this error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following from the linux shell to make a database dump (backup)

```
mysqldump -p -u[username] --no-lock-tables [database]>dumpfile.sql
```

replace [username] and [database] with the appropriate credentials of yours, like:

```
mysqldump -p -uroot --no-lock-tables mydb>dumpfile.sql
```